# Tag wiki gave me 4 points

Tags: support, tag-wikis

I have written one tag wiki [visual-studio] but I got 4 (2*2) rep points in return.
Is this a bug or what ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will get +2 for the excerpt and +2 for the full wiki, if you submit both.

Comment: Yes I did .. Thank you very much :)